# JSON data if/else parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, long-polling

I am doing some long polling (ajax) and I am looping the following portion of code.. There is code being executed above and below. This code is part of an internal messaging system. A certain portion of the page wil blink when a message arrives. If the user checks the message, it will remove the dash_notify from the JSON response, which needs to turn off the blinking. See below:

```
if (data.dash_notify == '1') {
    var x = '#dash_notif_blink';

    function blinking(x) {
        timer = setInterval(blink, 10);

        function blink() {
            x.fadeOut(400, function () {
                x.fadeIn(400);
            });
        }
    }

    console.log("initiate_dash");
    blinking($(x));
} else if (!data.dash_notify) {
    console.log("good");

    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

The following JSON response that gets sent to this code is:

```
{"current_date_time":"January 8, 2013 - 4:02 pm","dash_notify":"1"}
```

It understand the initial blink IF the above data gets passed. If the following gets passed:

```
{"current_date_time":"January 8, 2013 - 4:02 pm"}
```

Then it throws an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: timer is not defined
```

I cannot figure out how to fix the "else" portion working properly. If the code is initiated when the full dash_notify:1 response is sent, it works perfect. The button will blink, then if the user checks the message, it will no longer send dash_notify:1 and the button stops blinking. But if the code is initiated when dash_notify:1 is NOT set, it doesn't know what to do with the ClearInterval.

Basically I need the else portion fixed.

I have tried using different typeOf === undefined snippets, but it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

This is currently working.. Timer is now defined above the statement

```
if(data.dash_notify == '1'){

                            var x = '#dash_notif_blink';

                        console.log("initiate_dash");
                        blinking($(x));

                        }else if (typeof timer != "undefined" && timer) { 
                            clearInterval(timer);
    }               
                    }
```

This is working, but sometimes it trys to kill the timer but it doesn't actually do it. This happens every so often.

Comment: How is `timer` declared?

Comment: @josh3736 See the function above it.

Comment: if `timer` is only declared/initialized in the `blinking` function, then it makes perfect sense why you're getting that error.  Please clarify.

Comment: @EudisDuran You are right. This is the only way I knew how to do it. If it starts with the dash_notify data being sent then removed, it works fine. If the data isn't being sent when the polling starts then I get the error.

Comment: Okay, will make it an answer

Comment: I think your interval would need to be longer than your animation, OR check the animation to see if it is in progress before your add another...check the animation events in the jQuery doc for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is now working beautifully.**
**Thank you to everyone who helped!**

if(data.dash_notify === '1' && t === null ){

```
                    var x = '#dash_notif_blink';

                    function blinking(x) {
                        var timer = setInterval(blink, 10); //note the var keyword for best practice

                        function blink() {
                            x.fadeOut(400, function () {
                                x.fadeIn(400);
                            });
                        }
                        return timer;
                    }

                    console.log('initiate_dash_alert');

                    // Data is passed. Parse to see if dash alert should be called. Secondary protection for
                    // multiple timer creation.
                    if(t){return;}else{t = blinking($(x));}




                }else if (!data.dash_notify){    
                    clearInterval(t);
                    console.log('clear_dash_alert');
                    t = null;
                }else{
                    console.log(t);
                    console.log('no_push_events');

                }
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's not working because `timer` doesn't exist outside your inner `blinking` function. I'm making an assumption here that you don't have `var timer;` somewhere outside the `blinking` function, which is strongly likely given the error you're getting.

### Why this is happening:

If I'm right, and you're not declaring `timer` anywhere else in your code, then `var timer` is being implicitly added to the beginning of the `blinking` function:

```
function blinking(x) {
    var timer;
    timer = setInterval(blink, 10);

    function blink() {
        x.fadeOut(400, function () {
            x.fadeIn(400);
        });
    }
}
```

That makes `timer` a local variable inside `blinking`. Since you never pass it out of the closure, it doesn't exist once you're outside that function. So either you need to pull `timer` into the outer context (option 1) or make it available from inside `blinking` (option 2).

### What to do:

If you want access to `timer` outside of that closure, you'll have to do one of two things:

1: Declare `timer` outside of `blinking`:

```
 var timer = null;
 if (data.dash_notify == '1') {
    var x = '#dash_notif_blink';

    function blinking(x) {
        //etc...
```

2: Make it the return value of `blinking`:

```
var t;

if (data.dash_notify == '1') {
    var x = '#dash_notif_blink';

    function blinking(x) {
        var timer = setInterval(blink, 10); //note the var keyword for best practice

        function blink() {
            x.fadeOut(400, function () {
                x.fadeIn(400);
            });
        }

        return timer;
    }

    console.log("initiate_dash");
    t = blinking($(x));

} else if (!data.dash_notify) {
    console.log("good");    
    clearInterval(t);
}
```

Either one of these will work, and is more or less the same in terms of polluting the outer namespace. I prefer Option 2, because I feel like it's easier to work with a local variable until you need to return it.

---

#### Edit:

Your comment said the loop runs infinitely, which means you're creating a brand new interval and reassigning the `timer` variable every time. This is a separate problem from the one I described above. The old interval is still out there, `timer` just doesn't point to it anymore. So how can `clearInterval(timer)` clear out all those intervals? It can't, it can only clear the most recent one.

Basically, you've got a whole bunch of timers all trying to make the thing blink at once.

How you deal with this depends on what you're trying to do. The simplest thing would be to keep no more than one interval running at once, which means you have to clear `timer` every time.

```
//same as option 1 above except for `clearInterval(timer)` at the 
//beginning of `blinking`
var timer = null;

if (data.dash_notify == '1') {
    var x = '#dash_notif_blink';

    function blinking(x) {
        clearInterval(timer); 
        timer = setInterval(blink, 10);
```

If you need multiple timers running, you'll have to keep track of them all in an array or something:

```
var timers = [];
//...
   function blinking(x) {
        timers.push(setInterval(blink, 10));
//...
} else if (!data.dash_notify) {
   timers.forEach(function(timer) {
       clearInterval(timer);
   });
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work either! It's almost like it cannot find the timer. It still blinks, and I logged right after the else if, so I know it is trying to clear t.

Comment: so I am putting in console.log(timer); and I am seeing  that a random numbers gets returned from timer function.. shouldn't it have a name?

Comment: I removed my quickly typed answer and upvoted this one :)  See my comment on the OP question regarding the timer/animation

Comment: @JustinMorgan Does it help that another page loads in an iframe then the user clicks the button? It seems to have trouble when the iframe loads inside of the parent window with the blinking button.

Comment: @JustinMorgan I don't need multiple timers. basically I am polling the DB if a message has come through. It will start blinking a button to check a message. If the user dismissed the message either within the app or somewhere else, it write to the database saying it was read. I want the blinking to stop. Anyway I can get this to work properly would do. Someone else said that my blink animation may be screwing with the whole thing too. So the edit - Not sure if that's what I need. A single timer to blink a single button when a message comes through, then stop when its "dismissed" on the db.

Comment: @JustinMorgan "Cannot call method "forEach" of undefined. I added a few missing brackets also

Comment: @greycode - Please don't edit the brackets in. I left them out because it's not meant as a stand-alone block, you have to merge it into your code. If you compare it to your code, you'll see that I was just presenting a small snippet.

Comment: @greycode - Also, `forEach` is in the last code block, I meant the one above it. I think you should open a new question for this; as I said in my answer, it's a separate issue from your original one. If you do, let me know and I'll answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you did wrong with your typeof check since you did not actually show the whole code, but it should look something like this:

```
if (typeof timer != "undefined" && timer) { 
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Comment: Would be better to use the strict comparison operator in my opinion: `typeof timer !== "undefined" && timer`

Answer (score 0):

Basically define your variable `timer` before you enter your checking procedure (loop?):

```
var timer;

... some code ...

if ( data.dash_notify && data.dash_notify == '1') {
    ...
} else if (!data.dash_notify) {
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

You can call `clearInterval( whatever )` [without any consequences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout). Even if `whatever` is `null`, `undefined`, string and so on. Just make sure `timer` exist.

> Passing an invalid ID to clearTimeout does not have any effect (and
>   doesn't throw an exception). (MDN)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because `timer` is only declared/initialized in the `blinking` function. In the place where you call `clearInterval(timer)`, `timer` doesn't exist.